# Add a custom attachment to admin email-notification once order is placed in Woocommerce

Tags: php, html, woocommerce

I have a sticker company where customers can order custom stickers. Now i want to add the cutting designs of the stickers that has been ordered as attachment to the admin email-notification once order is placed in WooCommerce. It is an .ai file with the product's name and i want to add a dynamic attachments (based on ordered product name) to the 'new order'admin mail.

How can i add the .ai file to the standard 'new order' admin e-mail based on the product's name?

Comment: Doing a quick Google it looks like WooCommerce has an extension to attach files to emails maybe look into that. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/email-attachments/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add an attachment to admin email-notification once order is placed in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47776043/add-an-attachment-to-admin-email-notification-once-order-is-placed-in-woocommerc)

Comment: both options isn't what i'm looking for. Those solutions goes about static attachments. I want to place attachments based on the product's name that the customer ordered. Like the =IF function at Google Sheets. If product a has been ordered, then place product a.ai to the new order mail.