# How to send purchased digital products via e-mail in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-attachments, digital-downloads

I want to sell a .doc file document. when a user have paid, the doc file should be send to his email address and not directly download like it by default does. how can I do that?
it will be a downloadable doc file product that will be emailed to their email address

Answer (score 1):

Using `woocommerce_email_attachments` dedicated hook, you can attach items downloadable files to WooCommerce Customer completed order email notification as follow:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_downloadable_files_to_customer_completed_email', 10, 3 );
function attach_downloadable_files_to_customer_completed_email( $attachments, $email_id, $order ) {
    if( isset( $email_id ) && $email_id === 'customer_completed_order' ){
        // Loop through order items
        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
            $product = $item->get_product(); // The product Object

            if ( $product->is_downloadable() && ( $downloads = $product->get_downloads() ) ) {
                // Loop through product downloads
                foreach( $downloads as $download ) {
                    $attachments[] = $download->get_file();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $attachments;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

To make it work on Customer **processing** order notification, replace:

```
if( isset( $email_id ) && $email_id === 'customer_completed_order' ){
```

by:

```
if( isset( $email_id ) && $email_id === 'customer_processing_order' ){
```

---

Related answers:

- [Add an attachment to admin email-notification once order is placed in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47776043/add-an-attachment-to-admin-email-notification-once-order-is-placed-in-woocommerc/47776317#47776317)
- [Access downloadable data from WooCommerce downloadable products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62201288/access-downloadable-data-from-woocommerce-downloadable-products/62205042#62205042)
- [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)